# Не приходят сообщения на почту

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Не приходят сообщения на почту. На локалке все работает адекватно. Выгружаю все на хостинг и сообщения не приходят. В чем может быть причина?

Сама форма:

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-close">close</div>
    <h2>Заказать бесплатный звонок</h2>
    <form id="phone-call" action="" name="feedback" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" autofocus required>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите вашу почту">
        <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Введите ваш номер телефона" required>
        <button name="send" class="subm">Заказать звонок</button>
    </form>
    <img id="load" src="img/load.gif">
    <div id="answer"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#phone-call').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'feedback_lib.php',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#load').fadeIn(400);
        },
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#phone-call').serialize(),
        success: function(answer) {
            $('#answer').html(answer);
        }
    }).done(function() {
        $('#load').fadeOut(400),
        $('.subm').html('Спасибо за заявку!');
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if (preg_match('~[^а-яёА-ЯЁ ]~u', $name)) $result = 1;
else {
if (preg_match('/^\d+$/', $phone)) {
    $subject = "Письмо с Вашего сайта http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/";
    $header = "From <" . $email . ">\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    mail($subject, $message, $header, $recepient);
    mail($subject, $message1, $header, $copy);
    $result = 5;
} else $result = 4;
}
echo getAnswer($result);
```

Comment: почта небось на mail.ru ?

Comment: да нет.почта на gmail

Answer (score 2):

Установи **sendmail** на хостинг, если нету прав напиши админам, чтобы они установили.

Answer (score 2):

Во первых - посмотри ошибку после вызова mail

```
   print_r(error_get_last())
```

Во вторых - можно использовать эту библиотеку

[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

И с ее помощью отправлять письма со своей почты.